# Javaform: how to use a char in this case

Tags: java, string, char

I know that "how to convert from String to char?" has been asked many times, but I don't know why this is a problem for my project, since I don't think I'm trying to convert from a char to a string.

This is my code:

```
private void BtnAddClientActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    try {

        ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = ClienteDataSer.LoadData();

        Cliente C = new Cliente();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "reading: dni");
        C.setDni(Integer.parseInt(TxTDni.getText()));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "reading: nombre");
        C.setNombre(TxTNombre.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "reading: apellido");
        C.setApellido(TxTApellido.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "reading: sexo");
        C.setSexo(TxTSexo.getText()); //<--- error: "Incopatible types:String cannot be converted to char
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "reading: edad");
        C.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(TxTEdad.getText()));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se añade a la tabla clientes");
        clientes.add(C);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se guarda");
        ClienteDataSer.saveData(clientes);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se corre el metodo llenartablaclientes");
        llenarTablaClientes();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hecho");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faltan campos por llenar");
    }

}
```

(The multiple message dialogs were just debugging statements to see where the program is failing.)

Here is an excerpt from the class `TxTSexo.getText()` comes from:

```
    public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(char sexo) {
    if (this.sexo == 'M'|| this.sexo == 'm'|| this.sexo == 'f'|| this.sexo == 'F')
        this.sexo = sexo;
}
```

I've already tried to convert to String but it says error again.

If someone wants to read the whole project here is the [link](https://iberotecedu-my.sharepoint.com/personal/a1510114_iberotec_edu_pe/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=h7Uv%2FsSYg%2FqaZnfI4ZHPdrypJNeAOPNjt9PZnQeUE%2F8%3D&docid=09d9d8c151f6c4bf2b6318b34f77d635d), maybe there is something else you can do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sexo` property of the class involved has type `char`.  `TxTSexo.getText()` returns a `String`.  These are not the same thing, and there is no automatic conversion between them.  You need to perform a suitable conversion yourself in order to use `TxTSexo.getText()` to set the value of the `sexo` property.

If you can rely on `TxTSexo.getText()` to always return a non-`null` String containing exactly one character, or containing the desired character as its first, then you could use simply `C.setSexo(TxTSexo.getText().charAt(0))`.

If you need to accommodate `TxTSexo.getText()` being `null` or empty or containing leading whitespace, then you might instead do

```
char sexoChar;

try {
    sexoChar = TxTSexo.getText().trim().charAt(0);
} catch (NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    sexoChar = ' ';
}

C.setSexo(sexoChar);
```

It is possible that you would want to perform further validation or conversion.